# Use of SET to ignore pre logged users in a looping script

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, set

I am trying to use a set in order to stop users being re printed in the following code. I managed to get python to accept he code without producing any bugs, but if I let the code run on a  10 second loop it continues to print the users who should have already been logged. This is my first attempt at using a set, and I am a complete novice at python (building it all so far based on examples I have seen and reverse engineering them.)

Below is an example of the code I am using

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

######Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 45)
    s.run()

###### Code to get the data required from the URL desired
def getData():  
    post_url = "URL OF INTEREST"
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

######These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
              'rp' : '250',
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
#####Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

    xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
    pattern1 = re.compile('>&nbsp;&nbsp;(.*)<')
    pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
    pattern3 = re.compile('<span style=\'font-size:12px;\'>(.*)<\/span>')



##### Making the code identify each row, removing the need to numerically quantify the     number of rows in the xmlfile,
##### thus making number of rows dynamic (change as the list grows, required for looping function to work un interupted)

    for row in xmlload1['rows']:
        cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use in the pattern finding/regex

        user_delimiter = cell['username']
        selection_delimiter = cell['race_horse']


        if strikeratecalc2 < 12 : continue;

##### REMAINDER OF THE REGEX DELMITATIONS
        username_delimiter_results = re.findall(pattern1, user_delimiter)[0]
        userid_delimiter_results = (re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])
        user_selection = re.findall(pattern3, selection_delimiter)[0]

##### Code to stop duplicate posts of each user throughout the day

    userset = set ([])
    if userid_delimiter_results in userset: continue;



##### Printing the results of the code at hand

        print "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
        print "username = ",username_delimiter_results
        print "user selection = ",user_selection
        print ""



##### Code to stop duplicate posts of each user throughout the day  part 2 (udating set to add users already printed to the ignore list)

    userset.update(userid_delimiter_results)

    getData()


    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 300, getData)
```

Any comments will be greatly appreciated, this may seem common sense to you seasoned coders, but I really am just getting past "Hello world"

Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
userset.update(userid_delimiter_results)
```

Should probably be this:

```
userset.add(userid_delimiter_results)
```

To prove it, try printing the contents of `userset` after each call.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, it continues to print all users on second run of the code, it also printed `set([])` when asked to print `userset` any additional help will be very much appreciated. Many thanks AEA

Comment: When you make a new set, just do `set()`, not `set([])`.  After that, try simplifying your code down until you understand what it's doing--the code posted is rather too much for us to drill into.

Comment: p.s. `userset` continues to be `set([])` for both .add and .update

Comment: Well then you aren't adding anything, perhaps because you are creating a new set over and over.  Try using a set slowly in the Python REPL and see how it works.

Comment: For anyone else's benefit that may stumble across this post, the reason my code did not work was firstly the use of .update, printing .update after moving where I defined `userset` out before the `for` loop .update would print `u'1', u'0', u'3', u'5'` this progressed to `'1', u'0', u'3', u'2', u'5', u'7'` this turned out to be all the individual digits that made up the 3 user ids I was testing on. `.add` added the user ids as required. However the key thing here was moving the userset definition out of the for loop, otherwise it created a new set each time and never matched anything. Thanks JZ